# Equation of a phase curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been given the problem $$\dot{x}=-x$$ $$\dot{y}=-3y$$

I've sketched the phase portrait and calculated $$x(t)=c_1e^{-t}$$ $$y(t)=c_2e^{-3t}$$

I'm now asked to give the equation of the phase curve by eliminating t. I feel totally lost at this point. How should I approach it?

I'm guessing it's not too complicated and that I've just missed something.

Comment: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$$

Comment: To sketch the phase portrait I used $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-3y}{-x}=c => y=\frac{c}{3} \cdot x$$ in order to figure out the slope for various values of c. Is that what's being looked for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can eliminate $e^{-t}$ instead:
$$
    \frac{y}{c_2} = e^{-3t} = \left(e^{-t}\right)^3 = \left(\frac{x}{c_1}\right)^3
$$
By plugging in the initial conditions $(x(0),y(0)) = (x_0,y_0)$, we see $c_1 = x_0$ and $c_2 = y_0$.
Thus $y = \frac{y_0}{x_0^3} x^3$ is an equation for the solution curve.  If $x_0$ is positive, the actual orbit is the right half of the curve (excluding the origin), and if $x_0$ is negative, the left half.

If $x_0 = 0$ and $y_0 \neq 0$, the equations are $x = 0$, $y=y_0 e^{-3t}$.  The orbit is the positive $y$-axis if $y_0 > 0$, and the negative $y$-axis if $y_0 < 0$.

If $y_0 = 0$ and $x_0 \neq 0$, the equations are $x = x_0 e^{-t}$.  The orbit is the positive $x$-axis if $x_0 > 0$, and the negative $x$-axis if $x_0 < 0$.

If both $x_0=0$ and $y_0 = 0$, the orbit is the origin.

---

Your solution

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=  \frac{-3y}{-x} = c \implies y = \frac{c}{3} x$$

does not make sense to me.  How do you know $\frac{3y}{x}$ is constant?  From the differential equation with $y$ and $x$, I would separate the variables:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{dy}{y} &= \frac{3\,dx}{x} 
\end{align*}
Integrating each side, we have
\begin{align*}
    \ln y &= 3 \ln x + C \\\implies
        y &= e^{3\ln x + C} = e^C e^{3\ln x} = C' x^3
\end{align*}
We have assumed $x$ and $y$ were positive, but those other cases can be accounted for.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this. Both Eigenvalues are negative, it's asymptomatic stable. And from the phase portrait the curves seem parabolic in form terminating at the origin. How can y(x) then be cubic?

Comment: @AndyGrey: It's true the curves *seem* parabolic.  But remember they don't pass through the origin; the origin is its own orbit.  The two halves of $y=x^3$ are separate orbits.

Comment: Ok, yeah I can see that. Now I don't know which solution is being asked for and what to do about $c_1$ or $c_2$ equals zero. The above solution seems closer to what we've been learning but seems very different to your solution..